# CSS Grid Is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

This CSS grid is working on all browsers but internet explorer. Since edge came out it is working but people using outdated software would have problems.
How can I make this grid work in all browsers, or do I need to resort to divs?

````
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-areas: "Tall top left ." "Tall bottom- right ." ". . . .";
}

.Tall { grid-area: Tall; }

.top { grid-area: top; }

.left { grid-area: left; }

.bottom- { grid-area: bottom-; }

.right { grid-area: right; }
    
    
    .grid-container div{background-color: red; width:200px; height: 200px}  

</style>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Tall"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>```
````

Comment: grids do not work on ie!!! use flexbox

Comment: that stinks.. Ive developed a whole website using this... is there any alternative

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-css-grid-and-the-new-autoprefixer/    and     https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-faking-an-auto-placement-grid-with-gaps/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the [Autoprefixer CSS online tool](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to add auto prefix for your CSS code and I can see that it is giving the similar result as other browsers.

Modified code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v7.0.29,
* Autoprefixer: v9.7.6
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

.grid-container {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 0 1fr 0 1fr 0 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 0 1fr 0 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0;
      grid-template-areas: "Tall top left ." "Tall bottom- right ." ". . . .";
}

.Tall { -ms-grid-row: 1; -ms-grid-row-span: 3; -ms-grid-column: 1; grid-area: Tall; }

.top { -ms-grid-row: 1; -ms-grid-column: 3; grid-area: top; }

.left { -ms-grid-row: 1; -ms-grid-column: 5; grid-area: left; }

.bottom- { -ms-grid-row: 3; -ms-grid-column: 3; grid-area: bottom-; }

.right { -ms-grid-row: 3; -ms-grid-column: 5; grid-area: right; }
    
    
    .grid-container div{background-color: red; width:200px; height: 200px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Tall"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]